# GA4 tracking - Constantly clearing the ecommerce object creates noise

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, tracking, google-analytics-4

I am working on the code of a website that uses GA4 and GTM for tracking.

Following the recommendation here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#clear_the_ecommerce_object
I am pushing a { ecommerce: null }​ object to the datalayer prior to each event containing an ecommerce object.

As a result, the website's datalayer always ends up containing a large percentage of useless empty events, which are an annoyance in GA4 reports.

Is this normal? Is there a way to avoid this while still following the recommendation?

I have tried removing the `dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });` commands from my code. As expected, this had the desired effect of removing the empty events from the datalayer.

However, I do not have access to the GTM account that receives the tracking data. I am worried that removing the `dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });` commands against the recommendation of GA4's documentation may have a negative impact over there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.